# Excel VBA- ActiveX component can't create object Error

Tags: vba, excel

I want to move slide 2 after slide 13. I am trying to use the below code to do that but while running the macro I am facing the error ActiveX component can't create object. I am not able to find a solution to the same.

```
 ActivePresentation.Slides(2).MoveTo toPos:=14
```

Comment: There is no `ActivePresentation` in excel, so either your code does not concern excel but powerpoint, or your code is very incomplete.

Comment: @VincentG There is a detailed code in which I am copy pasting charts from excel to powerpoint. This is, therefore, just part of that code. What should I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve